# How to get Chrome's homepage URL from an extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to get Chrome's homepage URL from a browser extension?

I did not find any API method about this.

Comment: Are you talking about the "homepage_url" entry in the manifest?  You can use [`chrome.runtime.getManifest().homepage_url`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getManifest).

Comment: @Teepeemm No, I mean the homepage url of Chrome. can it read/get by Chrome extension?

Comment: What do you mean by "the homepage url of Chrome"?  Do you mean the new tab page?  Or the specific set of pages that you can have open when Chrome first starts?  Or something else?  How do you find out the url without using any API?

Comment: @Teepeemm thanks. Please go to settings , search for "homepage", then check "show homepage button", you will see a "Change" link, click to set the homepage url.

Answer (score 3):

No. Reading that setting is *not* exposed through any APIs.

You can under limited circumstances [attempt to *set* it](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/settings_override), but can't verify if that succeeded.